# Vue Component mounted before mounting the dependencies when using http-vue-loader

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-loader

I have a parent component (`CyaCandidateItem`) that has a slot to render a child component (`CyaCandidateItemActions`). A wrapper component (`CyaInformativeCandidateItem`) injects the child component into the parent's slot.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    components: {
        'CyaInformativeCandidateItem': Vue.component('CyaInformativeCandidateItem', {
            name: 'CyaInformativeCandidateItem',
            template: `
                <cya-candidate-item ref="self">
                    <cya-candidate-item-actions slot="action-buttons" ref="actions"></cya-candidate-item-actions>
                </cya-candidate-item>`,
            components: {
                'CyaCandidateItem': Vue.component('CyaCandidateItem',{ // EMBEDDED component
                    name: 'CyaCandidateItem',
                    template: `
                        <div>
                            <slot name="action-buttons"></slot>
                        </div>
                    `
                }),
                'CyaCandidateItemActions': Vue.component('CyaCandidateItemActions',{
                    name: 'CyaCandidateItemActions',
                    template : `
                        <div class="actions">
                            <button>Hallo</button>
                        </div>`,
                    data: function(){
                        return {};
                    }
                })
            },
            mounted: function(){
                console.log('mounted', this.$refs.actions, this.$refs.self, this.$refs);        
            }
        })
    },
    mounted: function(){}
});
```

Till thins everything works fine. `$refs.actions` and `$refs.self` points to the valid element. But when I render `CyaCandidateItem` through `http-vue-loader` both `$refs.actions` and `$refs.self` is undefined.

```
'CyaCandidateItem': httpVueLoader('/assets/CyaCandidateItem.vue')
```

Seems like the dependent component is being mounted before mounting the dependencies.

I this the expected behavour when using `http-vue-loader` ?